# When to use foldr with a continuation as an accumulation function?

Tags: haskell, io, fold, continuation-passing

There is a technique I've seen a few times with `foldr`.  It involves using a function in place of the accumulator in a `foldr`.  I'm wondering when it is necessary to do this, as opposed to using an accumulator that is just a regular value.

Most people have seen this technique before when using `foldr` to define `foldl`:

```
myFoldl :: forall a b. (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
myFoldl accum nil as = foldr f id as nil
  where
    f :: a -> (b -> b) -> b -> b
    f a continuation b = continuation $ accum b a
```

Here, the type of the combining function `f` is not just `a -> b -> b` like normal, but `a -> (b -> b) -> b -> b`.  It takes not only an `a` and `b`, but a continuation (`b -> b`) that we need to pass the `b` to in order to get the final `b`.

I most recently saw an example of using this trick in the book [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](https://simonmar.github.io/pages/pcph.html).  [Here](https://github.com/simonmar/parconc-examples/blob/3fca38f01f71639cc780473026fdaac679cc230c/findpar.hs#L21-L23) is a link to the source code of the example using this trick.  [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171114090047/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/books/1230000000929/ch13.html#conc-par_00000029) is a link to the chapter of the book explaining this example.

I've taken the liberty of simplifying the source code into a similar (but shorter) example.  Below is a function that takes a list of Strings, prints out whether each string's length is greater than five, then prints the full list of only the Strings that have a length greater than five:

```
import Text.Printf

stringsOver5 :: [String] -> IO ()
stringsOver5 strings = foldr f (print . reverse) strings []
  where
    f :: String -> ([String] -> IO ()) -> [String] -> IO ()
    f str continuation strs = do
      let isGreaterThan5 = length str > 5
      printf "Working on \"%s\", greater than 5? %s\n" str (show isGreaterThan5)
      if isGreaterThan5
        then continuation $ str : strs
        else continuation strs
```

Here's an example of using it from GHCi:

```
> stringsOver5 ["subdirectory", "bye", "cat", "function"]
Working on "subdirectory", greater than 5? True
Working on "bye", greater than 5? False
Working on "cat", greater than 5? False
Working on "function", greater than 5? True
["subdirectory","function"]
```

Just like in the `myFoldl` example, you can see that the combining function `f` is using the same trick.

However, it occurred to me that this `stringsOver5` function could probably be written without this trick:

```
stringsOver5PlainFoldr :: [String] -> IO ()
stringsOver5PlainFoldr strings = foldr f (pure []) strings >>= print
  where
    f :: String -> IO [String] -> IO [String]
    f str ioStrs = do
      let isGreaterThan5 = length str > 5
      printf "Working on \"%s\", greater than 5? %s\n" str (show isGreaterThan5)
      if isGreaterThan5
        then fmap (str :) ioStrs
        else ioStrs
```

(Although maybe you could make the argument that `IO [String]` [is a continuation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.2.0/docs/GHC-Types.html#t:IO)?)

---

I have two questions regarding this:

- Is it every absolutely necessary to use this trick of passing a continuation to `foldr`, instead of using `foldr` with a normal value as an accumulator?  Is there an example of a function that absolutely *can't* be written using `foldr` with a normal value?  (Aside from `foldl` and functions like that, of course.)
- When would I want to use this trick in my own code?  Is there any example of a function that can be significantly simplified by using this trick?
- Is there any sort of performance considerations to take into account when using this trick? (Or, well, when *not* using this trick?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have two questions regarding this:

For some large value of "two" :-P

> - Is it every absolutely necessary to use this trick of passing a continuation to foldr? Is there an example of a function that
>     absolutely can't be written without this trick? (Aside from foldl and
>     functions like that, of course.)

No, never. Each `foldr` invocation can always be replaced by explicit recursion.

One should use `foldr` and other well-known library functions when they make the code simpler. When they do not, one should not shoehorn the code so that it fits the `foldr` pattern.

There is no shame in using plain recursion, when there is no obvious replacement.

Compare your code with this, for instance:

```
stringsOver5 :: [String] -> IO ()
stringsOver5 strings = go strings []
  where
  go :: [String] -> [String] -> IO ()
  go []     acc = print (reverse acc)
  go (s:ss) acc = do
      let isGreaterThan5 = length str > 5
      printf "Working on \"%s\", greater than 5? %s\n" str (show isGreaterThan5)
      if isGreaterThan5
        then go ss (s:acc)
        else go ss acc
```

> - When would I want to use this trick in my own code? Is there any example of a function that can be significantly simplified by using
>     this trick?

In my humble opinion, almost never.

Personally, I find "calling `foldr` with four (or more) arguments" to be an anti-pattern in most cases. This is because it is not that shorter than using explicit recursion, and has the potential to be much less readable.

I would argue that this "idiom" is quite puzzling to any Haskeller who has not seen it before. It is a sort-of an acquired taste, so to speak.

Perhaps, it could be a good idea to use this style when the continuation functions are meaningful on their own. E.g., when representing lists as difference lists, the concatenation of a regular-list of difference-lists can be quite elegant

```
foldr (.) id listOfDLists []
```

is beautiful, even if the last `[]` might be puzzling at first.

> - Is there any sort of performance considerations to take into account when using this trick? (Or, well, when not using this trick?)

Performance should be essentially the same as using explicit recursion. GHC could even generate the exact same code.

Perhaps using `foldr` could help GHC fire some fold/build optimization rules, but I'm unsure about the need to do that when using continuations.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! Upon reading your answer, I realized that I didn't ask my first question correctly.  What I meant to ask was, `Is it every absolutely necessary to use this trick of passing a continuation to foldr, instead of using foldr with a normal (non-function) value as an accumulator?`  I have edited my question to add the missing nuance.  I'm well aware that folds and unfolds can always be replaced with raw recursion (and vice-versa)!  However, the rest of your answers were very helpful! (And thanks for picking up on "two" vs. "three" :-)

Comment: The DList example is a great example for when something like this trick is necessary (well, it is basically required when using DLists).

Comment: @illabout I think that one "needs" this trick when you have an input value that must be passed left-to-right (as in `foldl`), when instead the output must be produced right-to-left (as in `foldlr`). Perhaps one can also consider `mapAccumL` and `-R` as requiring some similar trick. Sometimes the trick can be avoided (e.g. `drop 1` should be doable without). Still, all the examples where this is needed feel somewhat `foldl`-ish to me.

Comment: It's noteworthy that `foldr` is sometimes a huge performance win over explicit recursion. If it's consuming the output of a "good producer", `foldr` can participate in list fusion.